# Find indexes of highest values in array. Can be 1-* values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, max

I know how to find the highest value and index in a array(list). But I dont know how to get the indexes if there are multiple highest values in a array. I want to create a method/function that can two things: fill the array(list) with only one index if there is only one highest value, or create a arraylist if there are multiple highest values. For example I give two array's:

```
Array1={42,3,42,42,42,5,8};
```

I want to get the all the indexes of value 42 in a new array(list).

```
Array2={42,3,35,67};
```

I want to create a array(list) with only one index of value 42.

Comment: What is this array(list) thing ? Do you mean array `int[]` or `List<Integer?` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for multiple indexes

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int array[] = {1,1,2,4,5,3,1,5};
int max = array[0];
list.add(0);
for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
    if(max<array[i]){
        max = array[i];
        list.clear();
        list.add(i);
    }else if(max==array[i])
        list.add(i);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

For single index, use an extra variable, to store it it.

Comment: This is a less efficient solution. A double pass will usually be better

Comment: @user2717954 agreed, but thats on the worst case. In the average case, it would usually be equal, if not faster, than looping twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 features and assuming the array is not empty:

```
int maxValue = Arrays.stream(array)
    .max()
    .getAsInt();
int[] maxIndexes = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .filter(i -> array[i] == maxValue)
    .toArray();
```

That's 2 iterations where first you find the max value and then the indexes where an array element is equal to the max value.

Some documentation if you are not familiar with some classes/methods above:
[IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--), [getAsInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario, having a small data set or a large data set, you might want to process the items sequentially or in parallel.

**NOTE:** the following code contains `JUnit` `@Test` annotation and `AssertJ` assertions.

**Solution: sequential, one pass, small data set**

This solution parses the array and keeps track of maximum and current maximum indexes. If a new maximum is found the indexes are cleared and the new maximum indexes are inserted.

```
@Test
public void sequential_algorithm_return_max_with_indexes() {

    int[] values = new int[]{42, 3, 42, 42, 42, 5, 8};

    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    List<Integer> maxValueIndexes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
        int value = values[index];

        if (value == maxValue) {
            maxValueIndexes.add(index);
        } else {
            if (value > maxValue) {
                maxValue = value;
                maxValueIndexes.clear();
                maxValueIndexes.add(index);
            }
        }
    }

    assertThat(maxValue).isEqualTo(42);
    assertThat(maxValueIndexes).containsExactly(0, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

**Solution: parallel, large data set**

Streams are flexible and allow parallel processing.

Bellow data is represented as a pair of index-value instead of an array. This is done in order to transform the array of pairs into a stream and keep track of indexes.

Because this supposed to work in parallel, `reduce` method accepts 3 arguments - initial value, accumulator and combiner. This means that multiple buckets run in parallel. For each bucket there is an initial value and an accumulator used to process items sequentially. Then the parallel results of buckets are combined using the combiner argument.

```
@Test
public void parallel_algorithm_return_max_with_indexes() {

    Pair<Integer, Integer>[] values = new Pair[]{
            new Pair<>(0, 42),
            new Pair<>(1, 3),
            new Pair<>(2, 42),
            new Pair<>(3, 42),
            new Pair<>(4, 42),
            new Pair<>(5, 5),
            new Pair<>(6, 8),
    };

    ValueIndexes<Integer> maxValueIndexes = Arrays.stream(values)
            .parallel()
            .reduce(
                    new ValueIndexes<>(Integer.MIN_VALUE),
                    (ValueIndexes<Integer> valueIndexes, Pair<Integer, Integer> value) -> {
                        if (valueIndexes.getValue() == value.getValue()) {
                            valueIndexes.addIndex(value.getKey());
                        } else {
                            if (value.getValue() > valueIndexes.getValue()) {
                                valueIndexes = new ValueIndexes<>(value.getValue());
                                valueIndexes.addIndex(value.getKey());
                            }
                        }

                        return valueIndexes;
                    },
                    (valueIndexes1, valueIndexes2) -> {
                        if (valueIndexes1.getValue() == valueIndexes2.getValue()) {
                            ValueIndexes<Integer> valueIndexes = new ValueIndexes<>(valueIndexes1.getValue());
                            valueIndexes.addIndexes(valueIndexes1.getIndexes());
                            valueIndexes.addIndexes(valueIndexes2.getIndexes());
                            return valueIndexes;
                        } else {
                            if (valueIndexes1.getValue() > valueIndexes2.getValue()) {
                                return valueIndexes1;
                            } else {
                                return valueIndexes2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );

    assertThat(maxValueIndexes.getValue()).isEqualTo(42);
    assertThat(maxValueIndexes.getIndexes()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(0, 2, 3, 4);
}

private class ValueIndexes<T> {

    private T value;
    private List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

    public ValueIndexes(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Iterable<Integer> getIndexes() {
        return indexes;
    }

    public void addIndexes(Iterable<Integer> indexes) {
        indexes.forEach(this::addIndex);
    }

    public void addIndex(int index) {
        indexes.add(index);
    }
}
```